# Voltage Regulators Transistors?

Tags: transistors, voltage-regulator

I am new to electronics and I was wondering, how can I distinguish a transistor from a voltage regulator and the opposite? For example here are 2 images, 1 of a transistor and 1 of a voltage regulator.

Voltage Regulator:

[image: Voltage Regulator]

Transistor:

[image: Transistor]

Comment: By looking at the number and googling its datasheet.

Comment: The same way you can distinguish between a box containing apples and a box containing oranges. By looking at the label.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I don't trust retail, I always open the box.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yo can't do this with components, unfortunately..

Comment: @EugeneSh.: you can, but you can't use them afterwards and you need enough equipment and knowledge to know better than to do it ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that easy - they use the same packe (TO220 to be precise). Assuming you don't have knowledge concerning how families of both devices are named, the best you could do - as PlasmaHH mentioned before, is to google the name of part you are looking at. Any electrical tests, performed without knowledge of part you're trying to test could lead to its destruction or your own harm. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Many components share the same packages. It works the same way with resistors--many resistors look identical, but have much different values. It's the same way with many IC packages (DIP-8, for example). The only sure-fire way to know the difference is to look up the part number shown on the case. For example, one of the most common voltage regulators on the market, the LM7805, is a 5-volt regulator most commonly found in a TO-220 package (though it comes in other packages as well). The TIP31 bipolar junction transistor is another common component in a TO-220 package. The only way to tell them apart is by the part numbers. The 7805 will say "7805" on the front of the case:

[image: 7805]

The TIP31 will say "TIP31" on the front of the case:

[image: TIP31]

Also note that there are many different variations of common packages, and you will not necessarily be able to distinguish components based on these variations. For example, some TO-220 packages have their metal tab enclosed in plastic:

[image: Plastic TO-220]

The above is actually a TO-220 that contains a pair of diodes with a common cathode.

Don't let these variations fool you. The only good way to know what you're dealing with is to find the datasheet for the part number on the device you have.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers:
If it's on a circuit board with component labels (Cnnn, Rnnn, etc*), I find transistors are usually Qnnn. Non-transistor 3-pin packages won't (shouldn't) be Qnnn. In the case of a voltage regulator, I've recently seen one labelled ICnnn. Other devices (or PCD manufacturers) may have different labels.

This won't provide much information about the device, but can be useful in the troubleshooting part of a repair. (it's a fast way of identifying a transistor)

Most of the time, however, the easiest is to type the first one or two groups of numbers and letters into your favorite search engine.

*Note: for Cnnn, Rnnn, etc, the "nnn" part is three digits. Labels usually look like "C301" (for a capacitor someone designing the PCB decided would get the number 301).